# How to pass user info to backend in angular

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, jwt

I have angular on the front end and .net-core on the back end. In my project, users can register and login.

I would like to explain my question with an example:

Let think about Facebook. Every user have photos. For a really basic function; `getPhotos()`. What should I pass between parentheses? I linked photos and users entity with Foreign key. So, I can add userId which I can take it from local-storage.

The question is that; Is it appropriate solution? And what is JWT for then? I hold username and Token on my local when a user logged in. But how and why will I use token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @devntc and welcome to Stack Overflow!

First of all I would encourage you to read more about [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) protocol and how [JWT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) works.

You are not calling a basic function. It's impossible to call a function from your front end to your back end in a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) application.

*I suppose that you want to make an HTTP call to your back-end to GET the user photos*

To answer your question: You don't need to add any parameters. Just the JWT as Authorization header.

- On user authentication, you create a JWT token.
- In that JWT you can add some basic information about that User that *anyone* can decrypt (Do not hold essential user information on JWT secret)
- On every call that you make, your back-end should understand who is calling from the JWT.

Read this e2e [article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) to help you implement that Authorization easily and with the right way.

*PS: This is not ASP-NET or Angular related question. It's more an SPA question.*

Comment: I mean HTTP call, of course I know I couldn't call func. from backend. Thx for the informations. Artical about Authorization is what I am searching for.

Comment: I understand, but it is good to say the things with their name. For someone new, it might be very confusing. Happy that helped :)